# How to use count with group by whole document in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nosql, aggregate-functions

I have a db like this

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId("1"),
        name: "John Doe",
        age: 25,
        address: {
            street: "123 Main St",
            city: "New York",
            state: "NY",
            zip: "10001"
        },
        images : [
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image1.jpg",
                caption: "Image 1"
                type: "jpg"
            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image2.jpg",
                caption: "Image 2"
                type: "png"
            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image3.jpg",
                caption: "Image 3"
                type: "svg"
            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image4.jpg",
                caption: "Image 4"
                type: "jpg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("2"),
        name: "Jack",
        age: 22,
        address: {
            street: "132 lake",
            city: "New York",
            state: "NY",
            zip: "10001"
        },
        images : [
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image212.jpg",
                caption: "Image 212"
                type: "png"
            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image34.jpg",
                caption: "Image 34"
                type: "svg"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
         _id: ObjectId("3"),
        name: "Random name",
        age: 27,
        address: {
            street: "Lajpat nagar",
            city: "New Delhi",
            state: "Delhi",
            zip: "121002"
        },
        images : [
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image5.jpg",
                caption: "Image 5"
                type: "jpg"
            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image7.jpg",
                caption: "Image 7"
                type: "png"
            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image12.jpg",
                caption: "Image 12"
                type: "svg"
            },
            {
                url: "http://www.example.com/image8.jpg",
                caption: "Image 8"
                type: "jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to calculate total number of records in which images array has more than one 'jpg' type image object in them.

**For above DB it should be 2
i.e. for Object Id 1 & 2.**
As in 1, there are 2 objects in the images array with type 'jpg'.
There are no such objects in Record 2.
While the 3rd Record also have 2 such objects.

How to do query in mongoDB, I have tried using $size & $unwind & $group operator but failed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something as follows :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        "$gte": [
          {
            $size: {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$images",
                "as": "img",
                "cond": {
                  "$eq": [
                    "$$img.type",
                    "jpg"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "res"
  },
  
])
```

See on mongoplayground https://mongoplayground.net/p/LCCcCNkyzZX

What i do here is a `$match` to get all document where length of `images` (filtered by `type = jpg`) is `>=2`.

Then i use the `$count` operator to retrieve the number of document matched previously.

Comment: Hi @fourchette,  your query doesn't seems to work as intended. If we remove the object which has 'image4' from the db, still the res shows two but I wanted only those count where 'type : jpg' is greater than 1

Comment: Then you can change `1` by `2`... or `$gte` by `$gt`

Comment: Edited my answer, should be working now

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you. I have used `$unwind`, `$match`, `$group` and `$sum`. Here is my code below =>
**Code**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$images"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "images.type": "jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Update**

**Check the link**: https://mongoplayground.net/p/lHDjL_25tyT

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$images"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "images.type": "jpg"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "total": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  // Condition after $group
  {
    $match: {
      total: {
        $gte: 2
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "1",
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "3",
    "total": 2
  }
]
```

**Note:** Please check the link : https://mongoplayground.net/p/zVi4MlOc-Fs

Comment: Hi @Srijon,  thanks for suggesting this method. How can I find total count of the records in a document which have this "total" >=2 (this is the field you created above).

Comment: @matrixman please check the update section of my code. Please let me know does it helpful or not. :)